# Removing Array Items from file

Tags: java, arrays, file

lets say we have a list of array items

ex:- a,b,c,d

which needs to be removed from a file which is full of data , I am missing something can anyone please help me in achieving this , thanks in advance

```
public static void rmvFromXML(String strFilePath,
        String strTmpFilePath) throws IOException {

    String currentLine = "";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    list.add("d");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(strFilePath));
    BufferedWriter fileWriter = null;

    fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(strTmpFilePath)));

    while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
        System.out.println("Trimmed Line    :- " + trimmedLine);

        for (String value : list) {

            System.out.println("Array Value:-   " + value);
            if (trimmedLine.equals(value))

                continue;

            fileWriter.write(trimmedLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
    }
    fileWriter.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: Some notes: such methods are **perfect** for unit testing. If you would be doing TDD; chances are that you would not need to come here and ask for help debugging your code. Because you would be writing and testing your code in small increments; and you don't end up with big chunks that "just dont work". Then: why are you using a list? If you put those things into a set ... you do a simple "set.contains"; thus no need to iterate your list all the time. Finally: "list" is a bad name. Names should tell what the objects behind them *mean*; not what they "are". (like valuesToDropFromInput )

Comment: you want to remove specific strings from a line  and . bt you are doing a equals on whole line with the string you want removed . thats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex. so that you wont have to iterate and check whether the 
line contains your strings

```
while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
Pattern removeWords = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:a|b|c|d)\\b\\s*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher fix = removeWords.matcher(currentLine);
String fixedString = fix.replaceAll("");
}
```

try doing it with above approach

```
input :
abcdefg

output
efg
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace provided substrings on each occurrence in lines from file, so replace it with empty spaces:

```
public static void rmvFromXML(String strFilePath,
                                  String strTmpFilePath) throws IOException {

        String currentLine = "";
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");
        list.add("c");
        list.add("d");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(strFilePath));
        BufferedWriter fileWriter = null;

        fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(strTmpFilePath)));

        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
            System.out.println("Trimmed Line    :- " + trimmedLine);

            for (String value : list) {
                System.out.println("Array Value:-   " + value);
                trimmedLine = trimmedLine.replaceAll(value, "");
            }

            fileWriter.write(trimmedLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        fileWriter.close();
        reader.close();
    }
```

So now for input:

```
sdfsdf
sdfsdf
sfsdfs
fa
a
 b
c
asdasdad
   d   
asdasd
```

We get output:

```
sfsf
sfsf
sfsfs
f



ss

ss
```

Comment: it doesnt remove  the a b  c and d.

Comment: Works fine, I had file with this lines:

sdfsdf
sdfsdf
sfsdfs
fa
a
 b
c
asdasdad
   d   
asdasd

And when I got output file with this lines:

sdfsdf
sdfsdf
sfsdfs
fa
asdasdad
asdasd

I updated my answer with full code which I used and used and result files.

Comment: well it doesnt remove a b c and d in the words

Comment: Then your logic is completely false. You work with lines, not words. What you gave, it checks full string if it is equal to any of given strings array. Not substring, but full string. I will update my answer with code that would delete provided substrings. I guess you wont to provide some string like "test" and then delete its every occurrence?

Comment: well op said he wants to remove a b c and d from a file im just removing every occurence of a b c d.

Comment: k that is better but what is op new update ? it was the question from the very begining +1.

Comment: I misunderstood him, he said he wanted to remove them from file and then wrote code about removing lines, so I guessed he wanted to remove lines not substrings (still he had error since he writes "b" to file when checking if it is "a"). I removed code about removing lines.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
    for (String value : list) {

        System.out.println("Array Value:-   " + value);
        if (trimmedLine.equals(value))

            continue;

        fileWriter.write(trimmedLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
```

by:

```
    bool found=false:
    for (String value : list) {

        System.out.println("Array Value:-   " + value);
        if (trimmedLine.equals(value))

            found=true;
    }
    if(!found)
        fileWriter.write(trimmedLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

The fileWriter.write call should be outside of the "for" loop.

Comment: `a,b,c,d`

which needs to be removed from a file which is full of data . which part of your code does that.

Comment: Removing means not writing them in the output file. The last two lines do that!

Comment: doesnt answer the question. he wants to remove a b c and d from  the file.

Comment: No he does not. You understood it this way. Read his code. He wants to generate another file not containing the a, b, c and d lines. I just replaced "continue" by a boolean and replaced the "fileWriter.write" call to the outside of the "for" loop.

Comment: If you are really concerned about "structure" ... then you don't move the file writing part out of that loop. You move it out of method completely. There is no need to couple those two things.

Comment: what do you mean he does not , 

`lets say we have a list of array items

ex:- a,b,c,d

which needs to be removed from a file which is full of data`

Comment: JUST READ HIS CODE! He miss-said it.

Comment: seriously @A.Wabbi .

Comment: As you are incapable of understanding his code @Priyamal, I will give you some hints. In the outer "while" loop, he iterates on all the input file lines. In the Inner "for" loop, he checks if the current line read from the file equals to one of the elements of the list. If so, he "continues" to the next line in the input file. I AM SERIOUS and you are a noob.

Comment: he is asking a question because his code doesnt work properly and how come you say that he mis said it.

Comment: His code removes the lines from the file indeed, but by creating another file, not on the same file. He should have said it this way. That's all!!!